# Const correctness causing problems with containers for pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, const-correctness, container-data-type

Given this code (C++, Qt containers are used but I suppose the question is universal):

```
// a containter for Item-s
QList<Item*> items;

// argument is const to prevent changing the item by this function
void doStuff(const Item *item)
{
    // find index of the item inside the container
    // indexOf() is declared as:
    // template <typename T> int QList<T>::indexOf(const T &t, int from = 0) const
    const int itemIndex = items->indexOf(item);
}
```

I get a compile error (MSVC2010):

> error C2664: 'QList::indexOf' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const Item *' to 'Item *const &'
>            with
>            [
>                T=Item *
>            ]
>            Conversion loses qualifiers

I figurer that since `indexOf()` is declared with a `const T &` argument, the argument would become a `const Item* &` (reference to a pointer to an Item that's const) which is easily obtainable from a `const Item*` argument. Unfortunately, since [`const T& t` and `T const &t` are equivalent](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-ref-alt.html), for some reason the compiler seems to treat the argument as `Item* const &t` which reads as "reference to a const pointer to an item" which is a different thing and doesn't make the `Item` pointed to immutable.

Am I interpreting this correctly? Why does the compiler screw things up even though the function is declared in a way that says it won't alter the argument? Is this really a case of how the const syntax equivalence can screw things up? Why does the compiler use the latter form over the former? What can I do about it if I want to store pointers in containters and maintain strict const semantics?

Comment: Try `items->indexOf(*item);`

Comment: @MadPhysicist: won't work, that argument is of `const Item` type, which is not convertible to `Item *const &` either.

Comment: Well, your QList is a list of `Item*`, not `const Item*` . Can you get away with `QList<const Item*>` ? remember `T*`, `const T*`, `T* const`, and `const T* const` are all very different things

Comment: @Mike: Not really, some other places I need to alter the items. Shouldn't be a problem anyway since indexOf() is a const function (doesn't alter the containter) and its argument is also const.

Comment: I think this is an artefact of pointer semantics combined with generic programming. A `const Item*` (also written as `Item const*`) and a `Item* const` are two different types; An `Item const*` cannot be converted to a `Item* const`. It is also an artefact of generic programming, as you *could* compare an `Item* const` to an `Item const*`, but the interface of `QList` seems not to support that (C++1y will give support for that with generic comparators à la `std::less<>` for Standard Library containers).

Comment: well really your function should be `void doStuff(Item *const item){...}` but there is not need you can just pass the ptr by value in that case so `void doStuff(Item *item){...}`

Comment: @Mike: Really?  I'm skeptical.  The OP wants to assert that `doStuff` doesn't modify the `Item` pointed to by `item`.

Comment: @DyP: Are you saying the problem is the interface of `QList`? There's no equivalent of indexOf() for `std::vector` AFAIK, but `std::find()` also accepts `const T& value` and I'm guessing it would exhibit the same problem.

Comment: @neuviemeporte In fact, `std::find(items.constBegin(), items.constEnd(), item)` should solve the problem, as it doesn't assume the type `T` is the same as the type of the dereferenced iterators. The Standard Library containers currently have "the same problem" with const-correctness for pointers, although they don't have as many *member* functions that could be problematic.

Comment: @JoeZ Yeah you're right on second thought I don't see any way that doesn't involve casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where you can use `const_cast` to remove the `const`-ness without violating the guarantee of your function.

```
// argument is const to prevent changing the item by this function
void doStuff(const Item *item)
{
    // find index of the item inside the container
    // indexOf() is declared as:
    // template <typename T> int QList<T>::indexOf(const T &t, int from = 0) const
    const int itemIndex = items->indexOf(const_cast<Item*>(item));
}
```

That's because `indexOf` is merely finding the pointer in the container, not dereferencing the pointer and mutating what's on the other side.

Comment: Is there no other way? I mean, const_cast seems so... overkill? Why did the compiler screw this up even though the function promises not to touch the argument?

Comment: @neuviemeporte : There are precious few places where you have to cast away `const`, thankfully.  But, the few that exist are unavoidable.  (Another place is the `free()` function, although that problem shows up more when implementing `const` correctness in C.)

Comment: @neuviemeporte : I _think_ this is one of the cases that C++11 was supposed to clean up with perfect forwarding.  In principle, it should be possible to compare a `T*` to a `const T*` safely, but the fact that `indexOf` takes a reference to the contained type means you're stuck trying to send a `reference to const T*` in where a `reference to T*` is desired.  My "rvalue references" understanding is very, very limited, though, so forgive my vagueness.  Any perfect-forwarding experts out there care to pipe up?

Comment: I don't think perfect forwarding can help with that. It's supposed to reduce the amount of copies necessary (in favour of moves), and to *forward* the l/rvalueness of the argument expression. (Not claiming to be an *expert*, though.)

Comment: @DyP : I think with some of the C++11 features, I can't even claim to be a newbie yet.  ;-)

Comment: Okay, I'm feeling a little reassured, I didn't expect a problem to come up in a piece of code as simple as this except for some big SNAFU on my part. ;)