# Const-correct pointer access to items in a container

Tags: c++, pointers, containers, const-correctness

### The Problem

I have a class holding a pointer to a container. The container offers access to subsets of its items. This is realized by a method with const and non-const version returning a vector of const/non-const pointers. The following code in a minimal (not fully functional) excerpt from a more complex setup:

```
#include <vector>

struct Entity
{ int dummy; };

template <typename Value>
struct MyContainer
{
    typedef Value* pointer;
    typedef Value const* const_pointer;

    std::vector<pointer> pointers() {
        std::vector<pointer> ret;
        return ret;
    }
    std::vector<const_pointer> pointers() const {
        std::vector<const_pointer> ret;
        return ret;
    }
};

struct MyType
{
    typedef MyContainer<Entity> ContainerType;
    ContainerType* m_data;   // I cannot make this a non-pointer attribute

    std::vector<Entity*> pointers() {
        std::vector<Entity*> ret = m_data->pointers();
        return ret;
    }
    std::vector<Entity const*> pointers() const {
        std::vector<Entity const*> ret = m_data->pointers();   // error!
        return ret;
    }
//  std::vector<Entity*> pointers() const {
//      std::vector<Entity*> ret = m_data->pointers();
//      return ret;
//  }
};

int main() {
    MyType obj;
    MyType const& constobj = obj;
    std::vector<Entity*> pointers = obj.pointers();
    std::vector<Entity const*> constpointers = constobj.pointers();
//  std::vector<Entity*> constpointers = constobj.pointers();
}
```

Clang 3.8.0 (also 3.5.2) reports an error:

```
error: no viable conversion from 'vector<pointer>' to 'vector<const Entity *>'
            std::vector<Entity const*> ret = m_data->pointers();
                                       ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The commected code compiles fine, however, my intent is to give const access to items obtained through the const access path (via `constobj`), hence the const method should return pointers of type `Entity const*`. Changing the type of `m_data` from `ContainerType*` to `ContainerType` solves the problem, but that's not an option in my original code.

### Questions:

1. It seems that `MyType::pointers() const` calls the non-const method `MyContainer::pointers()` through its attribute `m_data`, which is of type `MyContainer* const` (at least I think so). I apparently need type `MyContainer const*`. Is there an elegant solution to achieve this?
2. The not-so-elegant solution is to cast the pointer to a const pointer: `std::vector<Entity const*> ret = static_cast<ContainerType const*>(m_data)->pointers();` Is this considered a sensible solution?
3. More generally: is my design flawed, or am I just missing a detail?

**Disclaimer**:
I hope this is not a duplicate, it seems that someone else must have had the same problem before. Anyway, I did not manage to resolve this from reading related questions on SO. (The question
[Const correctness causing problems with containers for pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599033/const-correctness-causing-problems-with-containers-for-pointers) is different, it is about a container of pointers. The issue seems to be related, but the answers did not help me to solve my present problem.)

Comment: `m_data` is not `const` in your call hence will call the non-const overload again.

Comment: STL adopts a design with explicitly-named constant methods and return types, i.e. `std::vector::cbegin()`. Is it an option for you?

Comment: @Sergey Nice point. Worth to post as answer.

Comment: @Sergey Hm.... I don't see how that solves my problem. Do you mean that I should return a vector of iterators instead of a vector of pointers?

Comment: If you have access to experimental features, you might be interested in [`propagate_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const)

Comment: @tglas Sergey meant you could add a new member function in `MyContainer`, like `std::vector<const_pointer> const_pointers() const {...}`, then call it explicitly as `std::vector<Entity const*> ret = m_data->const_pointers();`

Comment: @songyuanyau Oh thanks, too easy :) Yes, that sounds like a sensible approach. I mean, even the need for cbegin() in STL always felt to me like hinting at a deep design flaw, but over time I got used to it.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Thanks a lot, I did not now about propagate_const. It looks like a useful feature and the cleanest solution so far, but I don't want to rely on experimental features for such a detail.

Comment: No, I mean you may return a vector of pointer from `pointers()` method and a vector of const pointer from.. let it be `const_pointers()` method. Thus, you explicitly diverse methods which return different types.
P.S. songyuanyao has already clarified my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write

```
m_data->pointers()
```

you are calling to the same function (the non-const one) because m_data is defined as:

```
ContainerType* m_data;
```

that is, a pointer to a non-const objet.

When you use constobj the compiler considers m_data as a const member (you can not change constobj), but in this object, the pointer still points to a non-const object.

I do not know what your application is, but you could consider to add a new function as "cpointers" to return const pointers even if the object is not const.

EDIT: I mean, something like this:

```
struct MyContainer
{
    typedef Value* pointer;
    typedef Value const* const_pointer;

    std::vector<pointer> pointers() {
        std::vector<pointer> ret;
        return ret;
    }
    std::vector<const_pointer> pointers() const {
        std::vector<const_pointer> ret;
        return ret;
    }
    std::vector<const_pointer> cpointers() const {
        std::vector<const_pointer> ret;
        return ret;
    }
};

struct MyType
{

    typedef MyContainer<Entity> ContainerType;
    ContainerType* m_data;   // I cannot make this a non-pointer attribute

    std::vector<Entity*> pointers() {
        std::vector<Entity*> ret = m_data->pointers();
        return ret;
    }
    std::vector<Entity const*> pointers() const {
        std::vector<Entity const*> ret = m_data->cpointers();   // error!
        return ret;
    }
};
```

Comment: Not really relevant; the problem is that the OP is trying to perform an implicit conversion that doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
std::vector<Entity const*> ret = m_data->pointers();   // error!
```

to

```
std::vector<Entity const*> ret = 
(static_cast<const MyContainer<Entity>*>(m_data))->pointers(); // OK
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution proposed in my second question. Could you answer that question, i.e., do you think that this is the "right" solution, and why?